# Why do some order products have a product_id of 0

Tags: bigcommerce

Product with id 0 is not retrievable. Why are some order products associated with product_id 0? Is this a product that was deleted, but and order was already placed?

[image: Product Id 0]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`"product_id": 0` indicates "custom product" which can be added both via Control Panel or API.

Search for "custom product" on Orders API documentation page for more details: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders (the page doesn't explicitely mention that `product_id` for custom products is 0)

Comment: Note: deletion of a product doesn't result in update of `product_id` to `0` for the products in an order; the ID stays the same, just the record in Products resource is deleted