# Do BigCommerce product SKUs with a product_id of 0 (zero) need to stay around, or can they be removed safely?

Tags: bigcommerce

I read this related article, but it didn't answer my particular question:
[Why do some order products have a product_id of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006161/why-do-some-order-products-have-a-product-id-of-0)

My questions: should I remove product SKUs with a 0-value for the product_id, or not?

If it depends, on what does it depend? Can a regular shop admin determine those criteria? Or does it need to be determined by an API technician?

Can a regular shop admin delete SKUs with a product_id of 0? Or not? And if not, then how?

A bit of background:

I have programmed a data integrator between our web shops on BigCommerce and our internal database systems. One of its functions is to update inventory.

Our systems store inventory by UPC. So in order to update the BigCommerce SKU, it first needs to find that SKU's product_id and SKU id. To do that, it downloads all SKUs that have that specific UPC: 
/api/v2/products/skus?upc=123456789

Now, for some UPCs that query returns multiple SKUs. The application takes the first one and updates just that. But if that first SKU has a product_id of 0, the update FAILS.

That has me assume that SKUs with a 0-value product_id are not based on custom products, as someone mentioned in the article I linked above.

Instead, it has me assume that these are invalid SKUs, that should be removed.

But there doesn't seem to be a way for a regular shop admin to remove them. So to remove them, I would have to send an HTTP DELETE command.

Before I do that, I want to make very sure that my assumption is correct.

Another option is that I alter the application flow, and rather than just updating the first returned SKU, it updates all of them, except the one with a 0-value product_id.

Who has experience with this and can help?

Comment: I've never seen a SKU with product_id = 0. As far as I know, SKU's in Bigcommerce can not exist without a product. They must exist as subresources of a product, so they will always have a product ID.

Answer (score 0):

The only time products should have an ID of 0 is if they were custom products. It would be equally unusual to see SKUs with an ID of 0. These should be safe to delete if you are still seeing them.

Edit: As it turns out, this was an issue on the BC side. It is now resolved and you shouldn't see products or skus like this.

Comment: equally unusual indeed